# Recyclerview is not displaying data when using generic adapter & viewholder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter, android-viewholder

In my android project, I created Generic RecyclerView's Adapter class & Viewholder class like below,

Adapter class,

```
public class BaseRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder> {

    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    private List<? extends Object> objectArrayList;
    private int layout;
    private BaseViewHolder baseViewHolder;

    public BaseRecyclerViewAdapter(int layout, ItemClickListener itemClickListener, List<? extends Object> objectArrayList) {
        this.layout = layout;
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
        this.objectArrayList = objectArrayList;
    }

    public BaseRecyclerViewAdapter(BaseViewHolder baseViewHolder, int layout,
                                   ItemClickListener itemClickListener, List<? extends Object> objectArrayList) {
        this.baseViewHolder = baseViewHolder;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
        this.objectArrayList = objectArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public BaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout, parent, false);
        return new BaseViewHolder(itemView, itemClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BaseViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return objectArrayList.size();
    }
}
```

ViewHolder class

```
public class BaseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

    private CardView cardView;
    private AppCompatImageView imgEdit;
    private AppCompatImageView imgDelete;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public BaseViewHolder(View itemView, ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        super(itemView);
        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        imgEdit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgEdit);
        imgDelete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgDelete);
        imgDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
        cardView.setOnClickListener(this);
        cardView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == cardView.getId()) {
            itemClickListener.onClick(view, getLayoutPosition(), ConstantCodes.ACTION_CLICK);
        } else if (view.getId() == imgDelete.getId()) {
            itemClickListener.onClick(view, getLayoutPosition(), ConstantCodes.ACTION_DELETE);
        } else if (view.getId() == imgEdit.getId()) {
            itemClickListener.onClick(view, getLayoutPosition(), ConstantCodes.ACTION_EDIT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        itemClickListener.onLongClick(view, getLayoutPosition());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the way I implement the above adapter & viewholder in my activity class

```
private class DispatchViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder {
    AppCompatTextView txtInvoiceNo;
    AppCompatTextView txtVehicleNo;
    AppCompatTextView txtPartyName;
    AppCompatTextView txtNoOfBags;
    AppCompatTextView txtMaterialType;
    AppCompatTextView txtWeight;

    DispatchViewHolder(View itemView, ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        super(itemView, itemClickListener);
    }
}


private class DispatchMaterialAdapter extends BaseRecyclerViewAdapter {

    ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    List<? extends Object> objectArrayList;

    DispatchMaterialAdapter(ItemClickListener itemClickListener, List<? extends Object> objectArrayList) {
        super(R.layout.dispatch_material_row, itemClickListener, objectArrayList);
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
        this.objectArrayList = objectArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DispatchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dispatch_material_row, parent, false);
        return new DispatchViewHolder(itemView, itemClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BaseViewHolder holder, int position) {
        try {
            DispatchViewHolder dispatchViewHolder = (DispatchViewHolder) holder;
            DispatchMaterialMd dispatchMaterialMd = (DispatchMaterialMd) objectArrayList.get(position);
            dispatchViewHolder.txtInvoiceNo.setText(dispatchMaterialMd.getInvoiceNo());
            dispatchViewHolder.txtVehicleNo.setText(dispatchMaterialMd.getVehicleNo());
            dispatchViewHolder.txtPartyName.setText(dispatchMaterialMd.getPartyName());
            dispatchViewHolder.txtNoOfBags.setText(dispatchMaterialMd.getNoOfBags());
            dispatchViewHolder.txtMaterialType.setText(dispatchMaterialMd.getMaterialType());
            dispatchViewHolder.txtWeight.setText(dispatchMaterialMd.getWeight());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dispatchMaterialMds.size();
    }
}
```

I have data in my objectArrayList list. I can print it in console, but nothing is coming in recyclerview. In recyclerview, it is only displaying empty Textview.

Following way, implement recyclerview,

```
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
dispatchMaterialAdapter =
                new DispatchMaterialAdapter(itemClickListener, dispatchMaterialMds);
            recycleListDetail.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recycleListDetail.setAdapter(dispatchMaterialAdapter);
```

dispatchMaterialMds is an arraylist of model class which is filled from the database's data.

Can you please help me, why my data is not getting displayed ?

Comment: Instead of this.objectArrayList = objectArrayList; please use addAll() method like this this.objectArrayList.addAll(objectArrayList);

Comment: @SaurabhVadhva, but I am able to get data from objectArrayList, actual problem is something different

Comment: Please check my code.

Comment: Did you add a LayoutManager for RecyclerView？

Comment: @SamuraiSong, please check the last code block of my question. I did it.

Comment: In your 3rd block of code; inside getItemCount(), there is dispatchMaterialMds.size(). I think that should be objectArrayList.size().

Comment: @dazed'n'confused, Thank you, Please check the other answers, I have implemented the way you suggested too. but my problem is different one.

Comment: why is `@Override public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BaseViewHolder holder, int position) { }` empty?

Comment: @MohammadTabbara, that's because it is generic class

Comment: @Bitcoin then why are you overriding onCreateViewHolder and getItemCount again in DispatchMaterialAdapter ?

Comment: @MohammadTabbara, ok then in what way should I implement it ?

Comment: @Bitcoin didn't you make it generic to just override onBindViewHolder as i see it your code inflates the layout with the sameview twice. will post it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made BaseViewHolder that did the inflation then redone it in the DispatchViewHolder not sure if this will solve the problem but there was repeated code.

```
private class DispatchViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder {
    AppCompatTextView txtInvoiceNo;
    AppCompatTextView txtVehicleNo;
    AppCompatTextView txtPartyName;
    AppCompatTextView txtNoOfBags;
    AppCompatTextView txtMaterialType;
    AppCompatTextView txtWeight;

    DispatchViewHolder(View itemView, ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        super(itemView, itemClickListener);
    }
}


private class DispatchMaterialAdapter extends BaseRecyclerViewAdapter {

    ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    List<? extends Object> objectArrayList;

    DispatchMaterialAdapter(ItemClickListener itemClickListener, List<? extends Object> objectArrayList) {
        super(R.layout.dispatch_material_row, itemClickListener, objectArrayList);
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
        this.objectArrayList = objectArrayList;
    }

@Override
public DispatchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dispatch_material_row, parent, false);
    return new DispatchViewHolder(itemView, itemClickListener);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BaseViewHolder holder, int position) {
    try {
        DispatchViewHolder dispatchViewHolder = (DispatchViewHolder) holder;
        DispatchMaterialMd dispatchMaterialMd = (DispatchMaterialMd) objectArrayList.get(position);
        dispatchViewHolder.txtInvoiceNo.setText(dispatchMaterialMd.getInvoiceNo());
        dispatchViewHolder.txtVehicleNo.setText(dispatchMaterialMd.getVehicleNo());
        dispatchViewHolder.txtPartyName.setText(dispatchMaterialMd.getPartyName());
        dispatchViewHolder.txtNoOfBags.setText(dispatchMaterialMd.getNoOfBags());
        dispatchViewHolder.txtMaterialType.setText(dispatchMaterialMd.getMaterialType());
        dispatchViewHolder.txtWeight.setText(dispatchMaterialMd.getWeight());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In the DispatchViewHolder:

```
AppCompatTextView txtInvoiceNo;
AppCompatTextView txtVehicleNo;
AppCompatTextView txtPartyName;
AppCompatTextView txtNoOfBags;
AppCompatTextView txtMaterialType;
AppCompatTextView txtWeight;
DispatchViewHolder(View itemView, ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    super(itemView, itemClickListener);
    //Initiliazation of new view?
}
```

Comment: in the above code, you just removed the onCreateViewHolder() method right ? rest code is same as mine, I tried your way, but nothing happened :(

Comment: I added something else i noticed Dispatch View Holder doesn't initialize the txtInvoiceNo and other new TextViews

Comment: Got it, Initiliazation was not performed in my code.

Comment: However I need to override OnCreateViewHolder() method, otherwise it was not working.

Comment: I added onCreateViewHolder in case someone else faced something similar.

Answer (score 0):

make change in set adapter code  like below.

```
        recycleListDetail.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    dispatchMaterialAdapter =
            new DispatchMaterialAdapter(itemClickListener, dispatchMaterialMds);
    recycleListDetail.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recycleListDetail.setAdapter(dispatchMaterialAdapter);
    dispatchMaterialAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and also check your adapter in bind view get the arraylist value and check arraylist type in getting and passing to adapter that same or not.

Comment: I have data in my objectArrayList list. I can print it in console, but nothing is coming in recyclerview. In recyclerview, it is only displaying empty Textview.

Comment: in adapter getItemCount() method in put objectArrayList.size().

Comment: I tried that way too, but nothing is getting displayed in Textview, however, If I print the value on console, then it is working. So I think problem is somehow in Inheritance

Comment: then pl give your passing list array with data into adapter then i can test it.

Comment: you can take any string, for e.g. TEST, forget the model class and consider it as string array

Answer (score 0):

above discussion i am make demo for recycler view and is wroking using simple string array..
Adapter class.

public class RecyclerViewAdpater extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    List mStringList=new ArrayList<>();// hear you can pass any pojo class object.
    Context mContext;

```
public RecyclerViewAdpater(List<String> mStringList, Context mContext) {
    this.mStringList = mStringList;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_main,parent,false);
    return new ItemViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String data=mStringList.get(position); // if you pass object of class then create that class object.
    holder.textView.setText(data);
 }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mStringList.size();
}

public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;
    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeData);
    }
}
```

}

then implement activity like below code put in onCreate view method ...

```
 recyclerViewAdpater=new RecyclerViewAdpater(mStingList,this);
    mRvData.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRvData.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdpater);
    chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Please check my question's generic adapter, I do not use `RecyclerView.Adapter` while implementation.

Comment: Are you sarfaraz ?

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return objectArrayList.size();
}
```

Comment: @Saurabh, I tried your answer, but it is not working.

Comment: @SaurabhVadhva I think I understand what you meant. @Bitcoin You need to return the size of `objectArrayList` in `DispatchMaterialAdapter` class and not the size of `dispatchMaterialMds`

Comment: well if I do dispatchViewHolder.txtInvoiceNo.setText("TEST"); then also it is not printing TEST in TextView, so problem is with generic ViewHolder