# method does not override method from its superclass : onBindViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

My this question is different from the previous one.

I have this genetic ViewHolder for RecyclerView,

```
public class BaseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

    private CardView cardView;
    private AppCompatImageView imgEdit;
    private AppCompatImageView imgDelete;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public BaseViewHolder(View itemView, ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        super(itemView);
        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        imgEdit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgEdit);
        imgDelete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgDelete);
        imgDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
        cardView.setOnClickListener(this);
        cardView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == cardView.getId()) {
            itemClickListener.onClick(view, getLayoutPosition(), ConstantCodes.ACTION_CLICK);
        } else if (view.getId() == imgDelete.getId()) {
            itemClickListener.onClick(view, getLayoutPosition(), ConstantCodes.ACTION_DELETE);
        } else if (view.getId() == imgEdit.getId()) {
            itemClickListener.onClick(view, getLayoutPosition(), ConstantCodes.ACTION_EDIT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        itemClickListener.onLongClick(view, getLayoutPosition());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is my genetic Adapter class for RecyclerViewer

```
public class BaseRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder> {

    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    private List<? extends Object> objectArrayList;
    private int layout;

    public BaseRecyclerViewAdapter(int layout, ItemClickListener itemClickListener, List<? extends Object> objectArrayList) {
        this.layout = layout;
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
        this.objectArrayList = objectArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public BaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout, parent, false);
        return new BaseViewHolder(itemView, itemClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BaseViewHolder holder, int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return objectArrayList.size();
    }
}
```

When I implement the adapter in my activity class, it shows me an compile time error "Method does not override from its superclass". I already checked similar questions on google &  in SO. You can see that there is not typing issue in my implementation. Then what is the actual problem & how can I resolve it ?

Comment: can you check this link for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46095866/getting-android-recyclerview-to-update-view-inside-react-native-component/46313257#46313257

Comment: I think `onBindViewHolder` needs `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` as a parameter. You can cast the object later

Comment: @ByteHamster, I am not able to get you, can you show me some example code ?

Comment: Replace `@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BaseViewHolder holder, int position) {
    }` with `@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    }`

Comment: @B.M isn't that the same code?

Comment: The first one has  `BaseViewHolder holder` as first parameter and the second `ViewHolder holder`

Comment: @B.M, Thanks, Somehow this error is solved.

Comment: @B.M, can you give suggestion on this question as well, please https://stackoverflow.com/q/49379746/9042972